# Getting Customer Names based on Inactive Products

Tags: sql, oracle

I am working on Oracle Server:

I have below table.  I am trying to get Customer where Product status is Inactive. But, if any product of the same customer Status is Active. I don't won't those list.

```
+----------------+---------+----------+
|     Client     | Product |  Status  |
+----------------+---------+----------+
| John & Co.     |   12548 | Active   |
| John & Co.     |   58451 | Inactive |
| Vector Inc.    |   12243 | Inactive |
| Vector Inc.    |   84425 | Inactive |
| Ambro Info.    |   11145 | Inactive |
| Infy Tech inc. |   12473 | Active   |
| Infy Tech inc. |   84847 | Active   |
+----------------+---------+----------+
```

Expected Results:

```
+-------------+
|   Client    |
+-------------+
| Vector Inc. |
| Ambro Info. |
+-------------+
```

Can we achieve this with Oracle Query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]you can follow below query.

```
create table #temp (cst varchar(50),prodid int,tag varchar(40))

insert intO #TEMP
VALUES('John & Co.',12548,'Active'),
('John & Co.',58451,'Inactive'),
('Vector Inc',12243,'Inactive'),
('Vector Inc',84425,'Inactive'),
('Ambro Info.',11145,'Inactive'),
('Infy Tech inc',12473,'Active'),
('Infy Tech inc',84847,'Active')

SELECT DISTINCT T.CST FROM #temp T
WHERE T.CST NOT IN(SELECT Z.CST FROM #temp Z WHERE TAG='ACTIVE')
```

Comment: It doesn't work when we have combination of Active and Inactive Product.

Answer (score 0):

use not exists

```
select t1.Client from table_name t1 where 
not exists ( select 1 from table_name t2 where t2.Client=t1.Client and t2.status='Active')

with cte as
(
select 'john' as client,12548 as product, 'Active' as status
union all
select 'john' as client,58451 as product, 'Inactive' as status
union all
select 'Vector Inc', 12243 , 'Inactive'
)select t1.client from cte t1 where 
not exists ( select 1 from cte t2 where t2.client=t1.client and t2.status='Active'
)
```

[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=8e9720022a232697517738ffbadb7ea0)

```
client
Vector Inc
Ambro Info
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick reply.

Not working when we have combination of Active and Inactive Product for the same customer. The Query still brings the Active Product Customer list.

Comment: @rocky09 it should work cause i have tested check the fiddle link

Answer (score 0):

Think it in reverse way, you need to achieve all client that is not in active list, therefore we can have a simple query: (I used `#temp` table to represent your table here)

```
SELECT DISTINCT client
FROM #temp
WHERE status = 'Inactive' -- just incase there are more status rather than 'Active and 'Inactive'
AND client NOT IN
    (SELECT DISTINCT client FROM #temp WHERE status = 'Active')
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below script,

```
create table #temp (client varchar(50),product int,status varchar(40))

insert intO #TEMP
VALUES('John & Co.',12548,'Active'),
('John & Co.',58451,'Inactive'),
('Vector Inc',12243,'Inactive'),
('Vector Inc',84425,'Active'),
('Ambro Info.',11145,'Inactive'),
('Infy Tech inc',12473,'Inactive'),
('Infy Tech inc',84847,'Inactive'),
('Infy Tech inc',84847,'Active')

SELECT DISTINCT T.client FROM #temp T
WHERE T.client NOT IN(SELECT Z.client FROM #temp Z WHERE z.status='ACTIVE' and T.client=z.client)
and t.status='Inactive'
drop table #TEMP
```

Answer (score 0):

You want one result row per client, so you `GROUP BY` client. Then just check that there is only status `'Inactive'`. If the only statuses possible are `'Active'` and `'Inactive'`, you can just ask for the minimum value:

```
select client
from mytable
group by client
having min(status) = 'Inactive'
order by client;
```

With more statuses you'd have to extend the condition, e.g. `and max(status) = 'Inactive'` or `and min(status) = max(status)` or `and count(distinct status) = 1` or use conditional aggregation instead:

```
having count(case when status = 'Inactive' then 1 end) > 0
   and count(case when status = 'Active' then 1 end) = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

I would simply do aggregation :

```
SELECT t.client
FROM table t
GROUP BY t.client
HAVING MIN(Status) = MAX(Status) AND MIN(Status) = 'Inactive';
```